# Indentation preserving formatting of multiline strings

Tags: python, format, string-formatting

I generate bits of (C++) code using format strings such as

```
memfn_declaration = '''\
  {doc}
  {static}auto {fun}({formals}){const}
    -> {result};
'''
```

Format strings are nice for this, but is there a way to make them keep the indentation level for `{doc}` here?  It's typically multiline.

I know I can just indent the string corresponding to `doc` by two spaces, I know there are plenty of functions to this end, but that's not what I'm asking: I'm looking for something that would work without tweaking the strings I pass.

Comment: Please show sample doc input string and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've posted your own answer and clarified at little more about what you want. I think it would be slightly better to implement it by defining your own `str` subclass that extends the way strings can be formatted by supporting a new conversion type, `'i'`, which must be followed by a decimal number representing the level of indentation desired.

Here's an implementation that works in both Python 2 & 3:

```
import re
from textwrap import dedent
try:
    from textwrap import indent
except ImportError:
    def indent(s, prefix):
        return prefix + prefix.join(s.splitlines(True))

class Indentable(str):
    indent_format_spec = re.compile(r'''i([0-9]+)''')

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        matches = self.indent_format_spec.search(format_spec)
        if matches:
            level = int(matches.group(1))
            first, sep, text = dedent(self).strip().partition('\n')
            return first + sep + indent(text, ' ' * level)

        return super(Indentable, self).__format__(format_spec)

sample_format_string = '''\
  {doc:i2}
  {static}auto {fun}({formals}){const}
    -> {result};
'''

specs = {
    'doc': Indentable('''
        // Convert a string to a float.
        // Quite obsolete.
        // Use something better instead.
    '''),
    'static': '',
    'fun': 'atof',
    'formals': 'const char*',
    'const': '',
    'result': 'float',
}

print(sample_format_string.format(**specs))
```

Output:

```
  // Convert a string to a float.
  // Quite obsolete.
  // Use something better instead.
  auto atof(const char*)
    -> float;
```

Comment: This is nice, indeed, thanks a lot!  Originally I was looking for a means _not_ to specify the indentation level, just deducing it from the format string, but that seems way more tricky.

Comment: Why did you import `string`?  It seems useless.

Comment: You're right, 'import string` wasn't needed — it was just a leftover from some experimental code involving `string.Formatter`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
'''\
```

The backslash will ignore all whitespaces up to the next character. Remove the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something which is light-weight on the caller site.  I can live with the following compromise: I use the fact that format strings are allowed to query for attributes (`0.foo`) or items (`0['foo']`) to pass the indentation level in the format string.

```
import textwrap

class Indent(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Indent, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, level):
        first, _, text = textwrap.dedent(self).strip().partition('\n')
        text = textwrap.indent(text, ' ' * level)
        return first + '\n' + text

def indent_doc(d):
    res = dict(d)
    res['doc'] = Indent(d['doc'])
    return res

format = '''
  {doc[2]}
  {static}auto {fun}({formals}){const}
    -> {result};
'''

specs = {
    'doc': '''
    // Convert a string to a float.
    // Quite obsolete.
    // Use something better instead.
    ''',
    'static': '',
    'fun': 'atof',
    'formals': 'const char*',
    'const': '',
    'result': 'float',
}
print(format.format_map(indent_doc(specs)))
```

that gives:

```
$ python /tmp/foo.py

  // Convert a string to a float.
  // Quite obsolete.
  // Use something better instead.
  auto atof(const char*)
    -> float;
```

I'd be happy to read opinions about that.

Comment: You've left some code out. The last line raises an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format_map'`.

Comment: Actually that's probably more a problem of version of Python: it appeared in Python 3.2.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map